Ubuntu 24.04 not updating
trying to update my laptop running Ubuntu 24.04 but it keeps giving me an error and won't do it, there's currently about 930 MB worth of updates available so far, tried to unselect updates bringing it down to like 100 MB but won't do that either,  using my phone's Hotspot and have also tried public Wi-Fi... what could be causing this?

Open a terminal. Run the commands sudo apt update and sudo apt full-upgrade, one by one. Post the output by editing the question. Edit link https://askubuntu.com/posts/1535912/edit

We need to know the exact errors to treat the issue, and the commands I posted in the other comment will tell us the errors
